# combination of string and numbers not comparing properly in c

Tags: c, pointers, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two strings using pointer . its working fine when i enter only string or only numbers.but when i enter combination of strings and numbers . even though they are different its returning both strings are same .

For example :

`hello123` and `hello321` both are returning same

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char *i[10],*p[10],sum;
    int j,k=0;
    clrscr();

    printf("enter the string\n");
    gets(*i);

    printf("enter the string\n");
    gets(*p);

    for(j=0;*p[j]!=0;j++)
    {
        if(*p[j]!=*i[j])
        {
            k=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(k==0)
    {
        printf(" same");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not same");
    }

   getch(); 
}
```

Comment: `char *i[10]` is not a string but an array of (uninitialized) pointers. Calling `gets` on `*i` is therefore undefined behavior. (Using `gets()` is a bad idea by itself anyway.) You need to fix that first. Then, use a debugger to examine you program's state. Furthermore, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Remove all the stars and you're good to go. What made you think that it'd be right to have *an array of 10 pointers to characters* anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare

```
char *i[10],*p[10];
```

where `i` and `p` are expands to pointer to an character array. Using this you can't compare single Strings!

Try the following changes-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
        char i[10],p[10],sum;
        int j,k=0;
        char *x,*y;

        printf("enter the string\n");
        //   gets(i);
        fgets(i, sizeof i, stdin);

        printf("enter the string\n");
        //  gets(p);
        fgets(p, sizeof p, stdin);

        x=i; y=p;

        while(*x){
                if(*x != *y){
                        k=1;
                        break;
                }
                x++; y++;
        }

        if(k==0)
        {
                printf(" same\n");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("not same\n");
        }

}
```

Output-

```
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs# ./a.out 
enter the string
hello
enter the string
hello
 same
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs# ./a.out 
enter the string
hello123
enter the string
hello321
not same
```

Comment: this one will work but i want to compare the strings using pointers.

Comment: "Use scanf to read the input from the user" - no. Don't. Ever.

Comment: so is there any way that i can compare string using pointers ?

Comment: @user2503585 why would you want explicit pointers in this case? You can do `char *ip = i, *pp = p;` and use the `ip` and `pp` pointers instead of the arrays, but it's pointless -- the arrays already decay into pointers to their first element implicitly.

Comment: @user2503585 see my edit about getting user input. `gets()` and `scanf()` are inherently dangerous, you should use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @user2503585 by reading the FAQ, in first place. Ask good questions, write good answers, show some effort.